# SQL Server - stored procedure can't see in database

Tags: sql-server

I accidentally created a stored procedure without assigning it to database, where can I see it?

How it's happened? In SQL Server Management Studio, I open file with the code that created the stored procedure and I clicked on execute. :/

I am using SQL Server 2017.

Thanks

Comment: Expand Master DB...and chech in the programmability->stored procedure folder. You should be able to find there.

Comment: The stored procedure was created in the database that was active in SSMS at the time you executed the SQL file - check that database for your stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!!!!

It was in the default database "master".

I found it because i run `EXEC sp_stored_procedures;` this get me a list of all stored_procedures.